# DataGridView cell treats empty editable cell as a null, ignores DataGridViewCellStyle.NullValue property

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with 3 columns, two of which are user-editable.

I was getting a NullRef exception when accessing the cell's value as such

```
 someObject.Property = dgv.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value.ToString()
```

Which was obviously because I'm not checking for null before using the value. So instead of just checking for a `Nothing` value (which I will do now, never fear) I decided to change the object that initializes the `DataGridView` to never contain null for the string property that populates the cell. I just used `String.Empty` instead.

I thought everything would be well and good, but it seems that when I edit the cell and leave it blank it treats it as a null value instead of `String.Empty`. I've handled the the `CellBeginEdit`, `CellEndEdit` and `CellLeave` events trying to find where it's getting this magical null value from to no avail.

I saw [the `DataGridViewCellStyle.NullValue` property on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.nullvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which I thought would be the answer but, as it turns out, the `NullValue` property defaults to `String.Empty` so that doesn't make a lot of sense.

Obviously the simple answer here is "just check for null before you use it", but why can't I force it to treat an empty string as an empty string instead of a null?

Answer (score 0):

datagrid cell values are objects, an empty string is null.

You could convert it to a string and then check for string.empty but it's not far off just checking if it's nothing.

```
dim _value as string = dgv.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value
someObject.Property = _value
```

or write a function to check

```
Public Function checkForNull(_value as object) as string

If _value is nothing then return string.empty else return _value.tostring()

End Function
```

....

```
SomeObject.Property = checkForNull(dgv.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value)
```